# File not found error, but file exists

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-applications, cgi, ubuntu-14.04

I am working on a simple webapp from Head First Python. I am using ubuntu 14.04. But it is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/server.py", line 1143, in run_cgi
    os.execve(scriptfile, args, env)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'/home/sarthak/Desktop/Learn/HeadFirstPython/chapter7/webapp/cgi-bin/generate_list.py'

127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2015 07:08:25] CGI script exit status 0x7f00
```

The file surely exists on the system and it is made executable.

How to fix the problem?

Comment: Show some code where the error is generated. That'll help figure out the problem

Comment: First, is `scriptfile` also the first entry in `args`?

Comment: Second, you really shouldn't be `exec`-ing a script; if that's another Python script, you should be `exec`ing `sys.executable` with the script as `args[1]`. The former _may_ work on Linux, depending on how things are configured, but it may not (and it may also give different errors than you'd expect when it doesn't). And I don't know what the default configuration for Ubuntu 14.04 is. Or whether you're in a chroot jail, or what. Unless you need to make sure it's run by its `#!` processor instead of by Python, in which case, never mind; `execve` the script directly..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem lies in the 'wrong' path of the shebang line (the first line which says `#!/usr/local/bin/python3`) of the generate_list.py file.

If you are using ubuntu the location of python3 is probably `/usr/bin/python3` (You can find out your python3 location by typing `which python3` into the shell/terminal). So you have to adjust the first line to the actual address of python3 in order to make your script work.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I have been struggling with the same problem for hours.